# I'm using struts2,i'm asking about the radio button validation <s:radio>

Tags: javascript, validation, struts2, radio-button

```
<s:form action="creatingcv" method="post" onsubmit="return valider()" id="frmSaisie"> 

<s:radio name="cv.gender" label="Gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" id="Gender"/> 

</s:form>
```

I used this javascript code but it didn't work

```
function valider() { 

    frm=document.forms['frmSaisie']; 

    if(frm.elements['Gender'].value != "")  {       
        return true; 
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Please choose your gender"); 
        return false; 
    }
 }
```

I tested with other components this javascript code and it worked well but with this one it does nothing.

I also tested `frm.elements['Gender'].checked != false` but it returns nothing.

Comment: you have name `cv.gender` and id `Gender` have you tried `getElementById()` method if JS?

Comment: Why don't you use struts2 validators? I put an answer down, but it can also be easier if you use a library like jquery --> http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: i tried with getElementById() but nothing works too.. thx  Umesh Awasthi

Comment: Pigueiras thx for your help..well at the beginning i enjoyed the work with struts2 validation based on action class..everything works well!! but as long as my project gets harder and complicated i have faced many problems such as I have to use the same action for many reasons!!i will give your my example below so you can understand me

Answer (score 2):

For those who still want to use same

This was my radio button

```
<td><s:radio id="SME_RADIO" label="SME_RADIO" name="SME_RADIO"  list="#{'1':'Passed','2':'Failed'}"  value="smeVO.SME_RADIO"  labelposition="left" labelSeparator=":"/>
```

and this is how you can do validation,if nothing is selected it comes undefined that's way i kept if condition like that

```
radioValidation()
{
var nameCHK ="SME_RADIO";
     var selectedRadio = $('input[name='+nameCHK+']:radio:checked').val();
    if( selectedRadio !='1'||selectedRadio !='2' )
       {
         alert( "Please provide Some Radio!" );
         return false;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

: CRUD of database!! in that case i have to do several classes CreateAction UpdateAction..followed by CreateAction-validation.xml and UpdateAction-validation.xml...but here i faced a problem of objects creation and variables between update and read..the ID that i have to pass from form to form using  didnt work.. i have 3 forms one for creating,listing,editing..to pass params from listing to editing...here i got the problems..i create an additional object databaseEdited and i get it from the other form..but the creating of the object is on the class Action that's why i have to work with one Action which contains all CRUD..even if i work with static...still the null java lang exception...

HERE IS MY FORM DATABASE

```
<s:form  action="createDb" method="POST" onsubmit="return valider()" id="frmSaisie">
<s:if test="dbs.size">
<table border="1px">
    <tr>

        <td>ID</td>
        <td>DataBase</td>


        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="dbs">
        <tr>

            <td> <s:property value="dbaId"/> </td>
            <td> <s:property value="dba"/></td>

 <td class="tab-td">
<s:url id="update" action="redirect">
<s:param name="databaseEdited.dba" value="dba"/>
<s:param name="databaseEdited.dbaId" value="dbaId"/>
</s:url> 
<s:a href="%{update}">Edit</s:a>
</td >

<td class="tab-td">
<s:url id="delete" action="deletingDb">
<s:param name="databaseDeleted.dbaId" value="dbaId"/>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{delete}"> Delete</s:a>
</td > 

        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
</s:if>
```

My DATABASE EDITING form

```
<s:form action="updatingDb" method="post" >
    <s:div>
<% as you see i get params from databaseEdited object but the id i ought to put it manually in action class --%>

        <s:textfield label="DataBase" name="databaseEdited.dba" id=DB />
    </s:div>
    <br>
  <s:submit value="Submit" />

     <s:reset key="Cancel"/> 

        </s:form>
```

In my action class:

```
package com.consoft.cv.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import com.consoft.cv.entity.*;

import com.consoft.cv.model.*;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DBAction extends ActionSupport {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DBMBLocal DBEjb;
private DB database;
private DB databaseEdited;
private DB databaseDeleted;
private List<DB> dbs;
private static int uid;

public DBAction(){
    try {
        Context context=new InitialContext();
         DBEjb=(DBMBLocal) ( context.lookup("DBMB/local"));


        dbs=new ArrayList<DB>();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String findAll() {
    this.dbs=DBEjb.findAll();
    return "success";
}
public String create()
{

    DBEjb.create(database);
    return "success";

}
public String update()
{//the UID got from redirect method
    databaseEdited.setDbaId(uid);

DBEjb.update(databaseEdited);
    return "success";

}
public String delete()
{

    DBEjb.delete(databaseDeleted);
    return "success";

}
public String redirect()
{
    //this is the key cause HERE I CAN KEEP PASS THE ID TO Update method
     **uid=databaseEdited.getDbaId();** 
    return "success";
}
```

of course there are getters and setters

BECAUSE OF THESE PROBLEMS I COULD NOT WORK WITH STRUTS2 VALIDATION

Answer (score 0):

Think that `<s:radio>` tag will be replaced with something similar to this:

```
 <input type="radio" id="Gender" value="Male"/>
 <input type="radio" id="Gender" value="Female"/>
```

So then, `frm.elements['Gender'].value != ""` will not work property since there are two elements that matches that. Check each element separately:

```
function valider() {
  frm=document.forms['frmSaisie'];

  if(frm.elements[0].checked == true || frm.elements[1].checked == true)  {       
    return true;
  }
  else {
    alert("Please choose your gender");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for replying but in my form i want all component from tag <s: >, in that case i will be facing a problem of components disorder..i found too many solutions with jquery and simple javascript but most of them worked with <input> not with <s:radio>!! if i can resolve the problem of component's disorder I'm able to do a gd progress in my project..

Comment: WELL GOOD NEW FOR COMPONENTS DISORDER I FOUND A SOLUTION            Ok I actually was able to solve by adding the them="simple" in the s:form element.

<s:form id="registrationForm" action="/registration/.action" method="post" theme="simple">
I guess if I don't add them property Struts2 UI components add their own stylesheet and therefore get weir behavior. ANY WAY NOW I CAN USE <INPUT> and i can run them all..